# How to read number of files on a Network Access Share

Tags: powershell

my code is currently putting files over on to a Network Access Share (NAS). This works great, have had no issues with it. But now I want to go and count how many files are currently in a specific folder that I have been writing to. From my computer it works fine, from the server I don't get anything back even though I can write to it. I'm kinda lost on this. Any help is appreciated.

```
$Miscdir="\\XXXX-NAS3CIFSXXX\STG_LIB"
$MiscNumbers = (get-childitem $Miscdir | ?{!($_.PSIsContainer)}).Count
write-host  "Current Misc files = $MiscNumbers"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you answered it looks like `-Recurse` is what you were missing. That would tell me the directory `$Miscdir` contained no file so a null was returned from count. To expand on what you did there are two approaches you could have taken. Calling `Measure-Object` the get the count is a bit redundant.

```
$MiscCount = (Get-ChildItem $Miscdir -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer}).Count
```

*or* if you have at least PowerShell 3.0

```
$MiscCount = (Get-ChildItem $Miscdir -Recurse -File).Count
```

Then your output string

```
write-host "Current Misc files = $MiscCount"
```

Comment: I want to add that in most cases you want to avoid using the `write-host` cmdlet. Just putting the quoted string on the line alone will have the same effect, and if the script is called from something else it will be sent back to the program that called the script. If you use write-host it will only write the text to the host and not pass the string back to something that calls it.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician This is true. However in some case like in the middle of a loop I would want to use `Write-Host` to convey simple debug information that wont effect the standard output stream

Comment: Well, that's what `Write-Debug` is for. Not quite as convenient I suppose for short scripts though. Check out [this quick write-up](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/why-doesnt-write-debug-work-and-whats-it-anyway) if the cmdlet seems useless to you. For longer scripts being able to just turn off the debugging output when it works is easier than going back and removing or commenting out all the write-host calls.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician My comment was more focused on _short scripts_. For larger ones I would use custom functions with Write-Verbose or Write-Debug as you said. Thanks for the convo. delete a bunch of write-host would suck nuts.

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue....

```
$MiscNumbers = Get-ChildItem $Miscdir -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Measure-Object
$MiscCount = $MiscNumbers.count
write-host "Current Misc files = $MiscCount"
```